# Get full servlet URL during startup under Tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat, servlets, tomcat7

I have a web application written using Tomcat 6 and I'm trying to make it work with Tomcat 7. During its startup the application, besides other things, registers its web service component at some remote directory. For this it needs to supply its own URL. The following (a little bit naive) method should return webservice URL:

```
import org.apache.catalina.ServerFactory;
import org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector;
.
.
.
private String getWsUrl(ServletContext context)
            throws UnknownHostException, MalformedURLException {
    String host = java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost().getCanonicalHostName();
    int port = -1;
    for (Connector c : ServerFactory.getServer().findServices()[0].findConnectors()) {
        if (c.getProtocol().contains("HTTP")) {
            port = c.getPort();
            break;
        }
    }
    URL wsURL = new URL("http", host, port, context.getContextPath()
                + C.WEB_SERVICE_PATH /* this is just a constant string */ );
    return wsURL.toString();
}
```

The `ServerFactory.getServer()` part is turned out to be problematic: there is no `org.apache.catalina.ServerFactory` class in Tomcat 7. Any suggestions on how to rewrite this for Tomcat 7? I would also be happy to have more portable, non tomcat-specific code.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem: I needed to know the port number to build a URL for a particular Tomcat instance, the port number might vary (because I run multiple instances for testing), and as of Tomcat 7 ServerFactory has gone away.

I wrote the following code to find and parse the Tomcat server.xml file. It doesn't parse much, just getting the HTTP "port" and "redirectPort" values. It depends on the "catalina.home" or "catalina.base" System properties, which should exist in any running Tomcat instance. The beauty is that it doesn't depend on any Tomcat classes, and uses the JVM's XML parser.

I hope this helps.

```
public final class TomcatConfigUtil {

private static final String CONFIG_FILE_PATH = "conf/server.xml";

private static Map<String, String> properties = null;

// No instances, please.
private TomcatConfigUtil() { }


/**
 * Get the configuration as a map of name/value pairs, or throw an exception if it wasn't found.
 * All values are returned as Strings.
 * <ul>
 *   <li> httpPort - the HTTP port</li>
 *   <li> httpRedirectPort - the HTTP redirect port (which seems to be the SSL port) </li>
 * </ul>
 * @exception FileNotFoundException if the configuration file wasn't found
 * @exception IOException if there was a problem reading the configuration file
 * @exception SAXException if there was a problem parsing the configuration file
 */
public static synchronized Map<String, String> getConfig() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, SAXException {

    if (properties != null) {

        return properties;
    }

    final File serverConfigFile = findServerConfigFile();
    if (serverConfigFile == null) {

        throw new FileNotFoundException("Couldn't find the configuration file.");
    }

    final Map<String, String> tmpProperties = new HashMap<String, String>();

    // Content-handler does the actual parsing.
    final ServerConfigContentHandler contentHandler = new ServerConfigContentHandler(tmpProperties);
    final XMLReader xmlReader = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader();
    xmlReader.setContentHandler(contentHandler);

    // Pass the config file as the input source for parsing.
    final FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(serverConfigFile);
    xmlReader.parse(new InputSource(fileReader));
    fileReader.close();

    return (properties = Collections.unmodifiableMap(tmpProperties));
}


private static File findServerConfigFile() {

    if (System.getProperty("catalina.home") != null) {

        final File file = new File(System.getProperty("catalina.home"), CONFIG_FILE_PATH);
        if (file.isFile()) {

            return file;
        }
    }

    if (System.getProperty("catalina.base") != null) {

        final File file = new File(System.getProperty("catalina.base"), CONFIG_FILE_PATH);
        if (file.isFile()) {

            return file;
        }
    }

    return null;
}


/**
 * ContentHandler implementation for the XML parser.
 */
private static class ServerConfigContentHandler implements ContentHandler {

    private final Map<String, String> map;
    private boolean inServerElement;
    private boolean inCatalinaServiceElement;


    private ServerConfigContentHandler(final Map<String, String> map) {

        this.map = map;
    }

    @Override
    public void startDocument() throws SAXException {

        this.inServerElement = false;
        this.inCatalinaServiceElement = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(final String uri, final String localName, final String qName, final Attributes atts) throws SAXException {

        if (!this.inServerElement && "Server".equals(localName)) {

            this.inServerElement = true;
        }
        else if (this.inServerElement && "Service".equals(localName) && "Catalina".equals(atts.getValue("name"))) {

            this.inCatalinaServiceElement = true;
        }
        else if (this.inCatalinaServiceElement && "Connector".equals(localName) && "HTTP/1.1".equals(atts.getValue("protocol"))) {

            if ((atts.getValue("SSLEnabled") == null || "false".equals(atts.getValue("SSLEnabled"))) &&
                    (atts.getValue("secure") == null || "false".equals(atts.getValue("secure"))) &&
                    (atts.getValue("scheme") == null || "http".equals(atts.getValue("scheme")))) {

                        final String portStr = atts.getValue("port");
                        if (portStr != null) {

                            this.map.put("httpPort", portStr);
                        }
                        final String redirectPortStr = atts.getValue("redirectPort");
                        if (redirectPortStr != null) {

                            this.map.put("httpRedirectPort", redirectPortStr);
                        }
                    }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(final String uri, final String localName, final String qName) throws SAXException {

        if (this.inCatalinaServiceElement && "Service".equals(localName)) {

            this.inCatalinaServiceElement = false;
        }
        else if (this.inServerElement && "Server".equals(localName)) {

            this.inServerElement = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void endDocument() throws SAXException {

        this.inServerElement = false;
        this.inCatalinaServiceElement = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(final char[] ch, final int start, final int length) throws SAXException { }

    @Override
    public void endPrefixMapping(final String prefix) throws SAXException { }

    @Override
    public void ignorableWhitespace(final char[] ch, final int start, final int length) throws SAXException { }

    @Override
    public void processingInstruction(final String target, final String data) throws SAXException { }

    @Override
    public void setDocumentLocator(final Locator locator) { }

    @Override
    public void skippedEntity(final String name) throws SAXException { }

    @Override
    public void startPrefixMapping(final String prefix, final String uri) throws SAXException { }
}
```

}

Comment: Interesting approach, though too dirty for production code.
+1 for originality.

Comment: It works, however it ties the usage with Tomcat 7. Additional, not for this reply but for original post, the .getLocalhost() performance is very poor in some system, likely due to look up IP6 from Java 1.4.1. I wonder if we could make a dump request to servlet itself after startup to get necessary info through HttpRequest.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used it, and it probably doesn't return a URL with the hostname and address, but is there any chance `ServletContext.getResource("/")` will do what you want? I know it's intended for accessing a resource internally by the servlet, but you never know.

Comment: It returns a **disk file system** based `URL` pointing to the root of the public webcontent. So no, this absolutely doesn't do what the OP wants :)

Comment: Okay. The API docs don't specify what kind of URL it returns, and I didn't have time to test it. Thanks for checking on that.